# Mysql select clause in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

hello i wannna create sql caluse using this function

```
function selectFrom(reqContents, callback) {
connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE ?', [ reqContents.attribute,
        reqContents.table, reqContents.GET ], function(err, tuple, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        callback(tuple);
    }
});
```

}

First parameter(reqContents) is array and i have to use this function. But when i wrote multiple where conditions(below example), this query can't operate well.

**Example :**

```
reqContents.GET = {
id : user1,
passwd : 1
}
```

Comment: You need to write your own query builder

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote to take the .GET params from reqContents and generate the where clause from its key, values

```
function buildQuery(params){
    // Join the attributes to be in the form of att1,att2,att3
    params.attribute = params.attribute.join(",");

    // Generate WHERE clause conditions with AND between them
    params.GET = (function generateWhere(keyValues){
        var str = "";
        for(var key in keyValues) {
            str += key + " = " + (isNaN(keyValues[key])? '"'+keyValues[key]+'"': keyValues[key]);
            if(Object.keys(keyValues).indexOf(key) != Object.keys(keyValues).length-1)
                str+= " AND ";
        };
        return str;
    })(params.GET);

    return params;
}
```

This is what you need to do:

```
function selectFrom(reqContents, callback) {
reqContents = buildQuery(reqContents);
connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE ?', [ reqContents.attribute,
        reqContents.table, reqContents.GET ], function(err, tuple, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        callback(tuple);
    }
});
```